# Wordpress: How to create a dropdown for users to sort posts by date, title, or custom field

Tags: wordpress, sorting, posts

I have a site for a client and one page displays posts from a custom post type. Its a record label and I created a custom post type for "releases".

A page displays all releases. I need to create a dropdown menu though that allows people to alter the display of the posts by Title, Date (post's date serves as "release date"), or Artist (custom field).

How would I code the dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

You would create a `<select>` input directly in your template for that page, assuming you have one (create one if you don't). You can then either use a `<form action="" method="POST">` wrapping the dropdown or some JavaScript to submit the form to itself (that is, `action="?sort"` or similar to submit back into your template). Both of those are fairly simple to implement, but just say so if you're unsure.

Then, in the same template file, before your `WP_Query` or `query_posts` (or `get_posts`, etc), grab the POST variable: `$_POST['dropdown_name']` and use an `if elseif else` or `switch()` statement to create your post query depending on that POST variable.

This is the easiest approach. Not sure what your level of experience is, say so if you got lost.